# Можно ли улучшить данную программу?

Tags: c

Юзер вводит свой возраст, и программа выдает его со словами "год", "года", "лет" (например, 23 года, 70 лет, 4 года).

Код Си:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    unsigned short age = 0;

    printf("Введите ваш возраст: ");
    scanf("%u", &age);

    printf("Вам %d ", age);

    if(age > 4 && age < 21)
        puts("лет.");
    else if((age %= 10) == 1)
        puts("год.");
    else if(age > 1 && age < 5)
        puts("года.");
    else
        puts("лет.");

    return 0;
}
```

Можно ли сделать код более эффективным, компактным? А как бы вы решили эту задачу?

Comment: маленькая ремарка - программа прежде всего должна быть понятной для человека. С помощью тернарных операторов ее можно сделать чуть короче, но от этого она станет лишь запутанней, а это очень существенный недостаток (при том, что вся эта цепочка тернарных операторов явно не сделает ее быстрее, что могло как-то оправдать эти действия). Поэтому стоит трижды подумать, прежде чем делать код менее читаемым в угоду размеру исходника

Comment: @dr_kraken, формат `"%u"` в `scanf()` относится к вводу переменных типа **`unsigned int`** (а у Вас **`unsigned short age`**).

Надо написать `if (scanf("%hu"`, &age) == 1) { ...`

--

Для х86 и одной переменной в программе это работать будет. А в остальных случаях -- не факт (в big-endian архитектурах работать однозначно не будет (прочтите [про порядок байт](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2))).

Про разницу размеров переменных (2 байта short и 4 байта int я просто молчу).

Comment: Спасибо, учту.

Comment: @dr_kraken, а что, сейчас набросаю...

Answer (score 5):

```
puts(((age % 10) == 1) ? "год." : ((age > 1 && age < 5) ? "года." : "лет."))
```

Как вариант.

```
include <stdio.h>
int main(void) { 
   unsigned short age = 0;

   printf("Введите ваш возраст: ");
   scanf("%u", &age);

   printf("Вам %d ", age);

   puts(((age % 10) == 1) ? "год." : ((age > 1 && age < 5) ? "года." : "лет."));

   return 0;
}
```

Или

```
printf("Вам %d %s", age, ((age % 10) == 1) ? "год." : ((age > 1 && age < 5) ? "года." : "лет."));
```

Супер компактно и нечитаемо :)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Мне ваш вариант нравится больше, чем мой.

Comment: Во втором варианте код не совсем корректно работает. При вводе, например 44, выводится 4 года. Т.к. изменение значения в age %=10, изменило и age в первом аргументе.

Comment: Убрать '=' и ок

Comment: Неправильно работает 

(собственно, как и оригинал, только ошибки разные).

Протестируйте с 32 и 114.

Comment: Deadkenny Если убрать = из age %= 10, прога будет неправильно работать, как и в первом случае.

Comment: Вы не учитываете 11 лет, 12 лет, 13, лет, 14 лет (а не год и года).

Comment: @Gimka я ничего не добавлял, просто написал компактно.

Comment: @Deadkenny
Я имел виду, что в коде автора выводится 11 лет, а в Вашем коде 11 год. Т.е. Вы переписали код в сокращенную версию неточно.

Answer (score 5):

Заметим, что у нас есть 3 варианта:

- лет
- года
- год

которые будут одинаково повторяться  в каждой сотне лет.

Причем, слово "лет" встречается чаще остальных. Еще можно заметить, что весь второй десяток -- это "лет" и во всех десятках годА с 5 и дальше -- это тоже "лет".

Слово "год" употребляется один раз в каждом десятке (кроме второго (*11 лет*)).

Поэтому начнем со слова "лет", потом выделим "год", а оставшимся вариантам будет соответствовать слово "года".

```
#include <stdio.h>

const char *
years_name (unsigned int age)
{
  const char *t = "лет";

  if (age % 100 < 5 || age % 100 > 20) // 4 < age < 21 это точно "лет"
    if ((age %= 10) == 1)    // здесь ИЗМЕНЯЕМ переменную age !!!
                             // для вычисления условия с ЕДИНИЦАМИ лет в следующем if 
      t = "год";
    else if (age && age < 5) // если кончается на 0, то тоже оставим "лет"
      t = "года";

  return t;
}

static inline int get_age (unsigned short *p) {
  return fputs("> ", stdout), fflush(stdout), scanf("%hu", p) == 1;
}

int
main ()
{
  unsigned short age;

  while (get_age(&age))
    printf ("Вам %d %s.\n", age, years_name(age));

  return 0;
}
```

И оформляем все это виде пары функций и тривиального цикла в `main`.

Comment: avp Весьма интересный подход. Мне понравилось. Спасибо.

Comment: Возможно такой (функционально эквивалентный) вариант 


    const char *
    years_name (unsigned int age)
    {
      const char *t = "лет";
      unsigned int d = age % 10, dd = age % 100;
    
      if (!(d == 0 || d > 4 || (dd > 4 && dd < 21)))
        t = (d == 1) ? "год" : "года";
    
      return t;
    }
    
даже лучше.

Comment: avp Да, действительно лучше. Спасибо большое.

Comment: Можно то же самое написать компактным, но пожалуй немного запутанным "почти однострочником"


    #define D(x)  ((x) % 10)
    #define C(x)  ((x) % 100)
    static inline const char *years_name (unsigned int age) {
      return (D(age) == 0 || D(age) > 4 || (C(age) > 4 && C(age) < 21)) ?
        "лет" : (D(age) == 1) ? "год" : "года";
    }

Вообще, когда адекватный алгоритм найден, все дальше это уже игры в кубики.

IMHO 2 последних варианта стали в процессе такой игры существенно лучше первого тем, что входная переменная не изменяется.

Comment: @avp: Если я правильно понимаю, вы забыли в проверке `else if (age && age < 5)` взять остаток `% 100`. Поскольку только он и важен, я бы начал функцию с `age %= 100`.

---
Update: А, нет, показалось, вы берёте остаток `% 10`.

Comment: @VladD, мне самому это изменение `age` внутри `if` не понравилось, поэтому сделал еще 2 варианта 

(в комментариях).

Comment: Объясните, зачем static в static inline int get_age (unsigned short *p) {.... и в static inline const char *years_name (unsigned int age) {....? Я так понимаю, что static переменная сохраняет свое значение между вызовами функции. Если же убрать static из вышеназванных функций, это ничего не изменит. Или все же static нужна?

Comment: @dr_kraken, в данном случае указание `static` ограничивает видимость функции текущим модулем (по умолчанию все функции видны отовсюду).

Comment: klopp Объясните пожалуйста подробнее.

Comment: @dr_kraken, практически в данном случае квалификатор (или как его правильно зовут?) *static* не нужен, поскольку мы не цепляем никаких внешних модулей (библиотек). 

Т.е. я его часто пишу "по привычке", чтобы локальная функция не пересекалась по имени с какой-нибудь внешней (иначе будут проблемы при линковке).

Ради интереса можете поизучать вывод утилиты `nm` (почитайте `man nm`) для объектных (т.е. .o (получаете gcc -c)) и загрузчных модулей с переменными и функциями с *static* и без.

Comment: @avp, аналогичная привычка :-)

Answer (score 4):

Разрешите мне пару слов по поводу этого.

Код настолько простой, что более *эффективным* сделать его нельзя. Хороший оптимизирующий компилятор из любого оформления исходников сделает практически одинаковый объектный код. Улучшить эффективность такого простого кода *вручную* на сегодняшний день невозможно, а если бы и было, задаваться такой целью не стоит: это микрооптимизация, оптимизируйте лучше на уровне алгоритмов.

Теперь по поводу *компактности*. Какова цель написания более компактного кода? Эффективности это не прибавит, читаемости — может, да, а может, и нет. Точнее, до некоторого момента меньший объём кода означает большую понятность, но начиная с некоторого момента понятность теряется. (Пример будет в конце.)

Итак, единственной целью улучшения кода может быть улучшение его *читаемости*, а следовательно, и *вероятности ошибок*, и лёгкости в *поддержке* и *модификации*.

Вот мой вариант улучшения читаемости.

```
enum RussianNumberCase
{
    Single,
    Some,
    Many
};

RussianNumberCase get_case_for(unsigned int n)
{
    unsigned int lastTwoDigits = n % 100;
    unsigned int ones = lastTwoDigits % 10;
    unsigned int tens = lastTwoDigits / 10;

    // 10..19 have special rules
    if (tens == 1)
        return Many;

    // otherwise, last digit determines the case
    switch (ones)
    {
    case 1:
        return Single;
    case 2:
    case 3:
    case 4:
        return Some;
    default:
        return Many;
    }
}

const char* years(int n)
{
    // таблицу с индексацией пусть за меня построит оптимизатор,
    // не хочу ухудшать читаемость
    switch (get_case_for(n))
    {
    case Single:
        return "год";
    case Some:
        return "года";
    case Many:
        return "лет";
    }
}
```

---

Обещанный пример того, как компактность убивает понимаемость кода. Сравните:

```
unsigned int SumOfBits(unsigned long long arg)
{
    unsigned int result = 0;

    while (arg != 0)
    {
        unsigned int lastbit = arg & 1;
        if (lastbit != 0)
            result++;

        arg >>= 1; // delete last bit
    }

    return result;
}
```

и

```
int r=0;do r+=arg&1;while(arg>>=1);return r;
```

Comment: @Gimka: хотелось бы услышать конструктивную критику.

Comment: @VladD, хороший рефакторинг.

Вот футбол в параллель с остальными делами закончится, вернемся к этой теме и  проверим насколько хорошо компилятор все сможет оптимизировать.

--

Если младшие цифры возрастов распределены равномерно, то возврат `Many` по первой цифре (вычисленной сразу) сработает в половине вызовов.

Comment: @avp: функция `get_case_for` имеет и самостоятельный смысл:

* год, года, лет
* минута, минуты, минут
* документ, документа, документов

и т. д.

Comment: @VladD, именно ее  я и имел в виду, 

    возврат Many по первой цифре

говоря об оптимизации.

Comment: @avp: Кстати, мы здесь вторгаемся в ту область, где JIT-компилятор может быть эффективнее обыкновенного компилятора. Например, он может спрофилировать частоту различных веток кода, и при «финальной» компиляции вынести самую «горячую» ветку вперёд.

Comment: @VladD
Никакой критики, просто личностные возражения :)

Все таки как бы Вы не хвалили оптимизацию компилятора, бывают моменты где это не срабатывает, как хотелось бы. Немного притянутый пример:

сhar a[] = "o4en dlinniy massiv";
for (int i=0; i<strlen(a); ++i) a[i]^=0;

Человек и компилятор увидят, что такой цикл бесполезен и если человек уберет его полностью, то компилятор все таки один разочек вызовет strlen(а), что приведет к полному проходу огромного массива.
В вашем ответе быстродействие 40 сек против 30 сек программы автора. И я был бы очень взволнован, если бы так писали мои коллеги.

Comment: @Gimka:

1. Во-первых, приличный компилятор выкинет весь код, включая и чистую функцию `strlen` (человеческий компилятор знает о чистоте библиотечных функций).
2. Во-вторых, основная идея моего ответа — не слепое доверие оптимизатору, а **ненужность микрооптимизаций**. Если вы не понимаете того факта, что читаемость на три порядка важнее микрооптимизации, и проводите оптимизацию без профилирования, я бы не взял вас даже миддлом.
3. В третьих, реальное быстродействие достигается простым нечитаемым кодом: <http://pastebin.com/kx5NgenY>. Бенчмаркайте на здоровье.

Comment: @VladD
1) Не знаю, что Вы называете приличным компилятором, и относится ли к ним например Visual Studio 2013, но хочется в это верить.
2) Я Вам про это и говорю, что нужно писать такой код, который в данном случаи будет уместен, а не впадать из одной крайности в другую, от микрооптимизаций не читаемого кода, до не написать ли мне побольше строчек кода, чтобы было красивее.
3) Хм, этот код куда более читабелен чем Ваш, он не имеет сложных конструкций, его поймет любой школьник, по Вашей логике он должен быть еще предпочтительнее :)

Comment: @VladD
И я сомневаюсь, что какой то нормальный компилятор выкинет strlen(a) из кода. Так как если он это сделает, то получится совершенно другая программа, Вы опять не понимаете главного компилятор не изменяет логику программы. Да, он может выкинуть цикл и присвоение так как это не меняет логику программы, а вот выкинуть strlen это уже поменяет суть программы.

Comment: @Gimka:

1. Возьмите `icc` с максимальными настройками оптимизации.
2. Важен смысл. Очевидно, что явное указание логики (выбираем по цифрам) лучше, чем «скомпилированная» в таблицу логика. Попробуйте, например, почитать таблицы yacc.
3. Очевидно, что логика, размазанная по 100 строчкам, гораздо хуже поддаётся поддержке. Вы, например, заметили, что для индекса 84 ошибка?
4. Другая программа не получится. Компилятор имеет право на **любое** преобразование кода, не меняющее observable behaviour. В частности, все вычисления могут быть перенесены в compile time, и оставлен лишь финальный `cout`.

Comment: @VladD
2,3) У меня все же складывается впечатление, что Вы считаете, что я поставил Вам минус за то что для Вас важнее читабельность и поддержка кода, чем его размер и микроскопические оптимизации. Я этого как раз не отрицал, а наоборот отнес Ваш код к не сильно то читабельному и без нужды затянутым, по крайней мере код автора (если вынести присвоение из if) для меня выглядит куда приятнее.

Comment: @VladD
1,4) Извините, у меня нет icc, Вы можете проверить сами и поделиться результатом? :) Скорее всего здесь Вы меня опять не поняли. Вы говорите, что не стоит пытаться улучшить код как то вручную, что компилятор имеет право на любое преобразование и все сделает как надо. Я же пытаюсь Вам сказать, что компилятор может не сделать того что Вы от него ждете, не из-за того что ему нельзя преобразовать какой то код, а из-за того что Вы считаете, что он может это сделать и логика не измениться.

Comment: @VladD
Я как раз и хочу сказать, что Вы не видите «скомпилированную» в таблицу логику и можете допустить "ошибку" в коде, которая не даст компилятору оптимизировать это. И в моем наигранном примере я пытался продемонстрировать что то подобное. Вы видите цикл и считаете, что компилятор может его полностью удалить, и компилятор видит что этот цикл можно удалить, но также он еще видит, что если он удалит strlen, то программа начнет работать по другому в случаях когда есть ноль в массиве и когда его нет, поэтому он и должен оставить этот strlen, чтобы сохранить логику программы.

Comment: @VladD, @Gimka, ну и спор у вас разгорелся...

Понятно же, что можно объединить варианты с красивой и понятной  логикой и таблицей в одну программу.

Если таблица еще не инициализирована, то *красивый код* ее заполняет. Далее работает эффективный табличный алгоритм.

--

Кстати, @Gimka, Вы явно преувеличиваете неэффективность кода @VladD (функция `RussianNumberCase get_case_for(unsigned int n)
`).

Если не верите, то просто напишите измеритель и проверьте.

Comment: @Gimka: Нет, у меня нет под рукой icc. Но gcc прекрасно справляется: <http://pastebin.com/Ur7Gb90U>. Хороший компилятор умеет выкидывать всё лишнее. Ваш ход.

(Чтобы понять, почему компилятор имеет право выкинуть strlen, почитайте всё же про undefined behaviour.)

Comment: Особо "радует" такая "забота" компилятора в подбном коде

    clock_t t = clock();
    char a[] = "o4en dlinniy massiv";
    for (int i=0; i<strlen(a); ++i)
      a[i]^=0;
    cout << clock() - t << '\n';
    return 0;

Между прочим, весьма жизненный случай при измерении времени выполнения.

Особенно обескураживает, если мерять функцию с кодом в этом же файле, а компилятор подставив константные аргументы вычисляет получаемый результат на стадии компиляции (правильный результат видим на печати, а время стремится к 0).

(только на практике clock-ами измерять не стоит).

Comment: @avp: Угу, сталкивался с таким. Для борьбы с этим я во всех бенчмарках, которые использовал здесь на сайте, аккумулирую результат и вывожу его после остановки таймера на консоль. Но компилятор всё же имеет право выполнить все вычисления в compile-time, поэтому я ещё и беру начальные данные из (например) генератора случайных чисел или текущего времени.

Answer (score 0):

Вот это ничего себе, из самой неприметной задачи раздули чуть ли не войну :) вот доведу до ума свой Game of Life и тоже вкину во благо общественности. А если по сути, тут оптимизоровать особо и нечего, разве что учесть статистические данные и начинать проверки с самых частых, помоему остальное мелочь, если конечно сильно не грубить. Ну и собрать все if'ы в один switch.

Comment: Ну, у нас же форум, всякий вопрос на нём — лишь повод пообщаться. :-D